# How To Make My Text Appear/Disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

So I just recently asked this question but I think I needed to make what I was asking more clear.

My assignment wants me to be able to click a heading and have a paragraph appear, and then when I click on the heading again, it should disappear. I can make it appear, however, I am so lost as to how I can make it disappear. This is the code I have so far:

```
function showArticle(id) {
document.getElementById(id).style.display="block";

<h4 onclick="showArticle('Heading1')">Heading1 </h4>
<p  id="Heading1" class="invisi">
```

If anyone could help me out and let me know what I should put in there that would be fantastic!!!!

Comment: read on click event handler and also toggle function for [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: Did you try jQuery toggle?

Comment: Did you look at what the `invisi` class is? It will show you how the element is hidden to start with, or you could try looking up [possible values for the `.style.display` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display). Or, better, remove that class to show the element, and re-add the class to hide it again.